# How to add and refresh a group of ImageViews in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need to loop through an `ArrayList` of objects and add their `ImageView`s to my main `Group` which is `root` in the code below. This is what I came up so far but still not working. Any idea?

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    ImageView ii =myList.get(i).imageView;
    root.getChildren().remove(bGroup);
    Group bGroup = new Group();
    bGroup.getChildren().add(ii); //NullPointerException
    root.getChildren().add(bGroup);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means. You get an exception? It doesn't compile? Something else?

Comment: Also, I just made the effort to fix your formatting. Is there some reason you felt it necessary to destroy it again?

Comment: i get NullPointerException

Comment: @James_D i made a change

Comment: 1. Include the complete stack trace in the question, and indicate the line in your code that is throwing it. 2. If you're going to make edits, please make an effort to format the question appropriately, so that it's easy to read. You can get information on how to format your code [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/).

Answer (score 0):

myList.get(i) instead of myList.get(1)?

Comment: my bad,just fixed it and yet not working

Comment: Please explain your exact problem. What exactly is not working? Any error message? Exception? No data in root.getChildren() alter adding? Something Else?